# Function Within a View SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, function, view

Hey I am having a problem with a View I am trying to create I am trying to get the Full Address of a member be Displayed in correlation with the MemberID of my Member Table along with a few other fields in other tables but the FullAddress and MFullAddress are both coming up as NULL Values and I am not sure why hope someone can help. Below is the Code for my View.

```
SELECT        dbo.Member.MemberID, dbo.Member.Title + ' ' + dbo.Member.Forename + ' ' + dbo.Member.Surname AS Fullname, dbo.GetMemberFullAddress(dbo.Member.MemberID) AS FullAddress, 
                     dbo.GetMemberFullMailingAddress(dbo.Member.MemberID) AS MFullAddress, dbo.Lookup_ActionType.Description, dbo.Payment.Amount
FROM            dbo.Payment RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.Member ON dbo.Payment.PaymentID = dbo.Member.MemberID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.Action LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.Lookup_ActionType ON dbo.Action.ActionTypeID = dbo.Lookup_ActionType.ActionTypeID ON dbo.Member.MemberID = dbo.Action.MemberID
WHERE        (dbo.Member.MemberID = dbo.Member.MemberID)
```

And here are Both of my Functions Called **dbo.GetFullMemberAddress**  The Mfulladdress function is the same only different fields

```
    USE [ICOM.Database]
    GO
    /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetMemberFullAddress]    Script Date: 22/10/2014     11:53:38 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Richard Glass>
-- Create date: <22/10/2014>
-- Description: <Returns Full Address>
-- =============================================

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMemberFullAddress] 
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    (@MemberID as integer)
RETURNS varchar(250) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @AddressLine as varchar(40)
DECLARE @FullAddress as varchar(250)
SET @FullAddress = (SELECT LTRIM(ISNULL(Title + ' ', '') + ForeName + ' ' + Surname) AS FullName FROM Member WHERE MemberID = @MemberID) + CHAR(10)

SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
SET @AddressLine = (SELECT Member.AddressLine1 FROM Member WHERE MemberID = @MemberID)
SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
        SET @AddressLine = (SELECT AddressLine2 FROM Member WHERE MemberID = @MemberID)
IF @AddressLine <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
    END
        SET @AddressLine = (SELECT AddressLine3 FROM Member WHERE MemberID = @MemberID)
IF @AddressLine <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
    END
SET @AddressLine = (SELECT Town FROM Member WHERE MemberID = @MemberID)
IF @AddressLine <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
    END
SET @AddressLine = (SELECT PostCode FROM Member WHERE MemberID = @MemberID)
SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine

RETURN @FullAddress
END
```

AND

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because concatenetating NULL with anything yields `NULL` by default. At the start of the function you have:

```
DECLARE @AddressLine as varchar(40)
DECLARE @FullAddress as varchar(250)
SET @FullAddress = (SELECT LTRIM(ISNULL(Title + ' ', '') + ForeName + ' ' + Surname) AS FullName FROM Member WHERE MemberID = @MemberID) + CHAR(10)

SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
```

And the problem line is:

```
SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
```

At this point `@AddressLine` is `NULL`, therefore you set `@FullAddress` to `NULL`.

You can get your full address though in a much less convoluted fashion, something like:

```
(LTRIM(ISNULL(Title + ' ', '') + ForeName + ' ' + Surname) + ',' + 
CASE WHEN ISNULL(AddressLine1, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE AddressLine1 + ',' END  + 
CASE WHEN ISNULL(AddressLine2, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE AddressLine2 + ',' END  + 
CASE WHEN ISNULL(AddressLine3, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE AddressLine3 + ',' END  + 
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Town, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE Town + ',' END +
CASE WHEN ISNULL(PostCode, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE PostCode END
```

Although seemingly quite verbose, it does not require repeatedly querying the member table. You could then just add this as a computed column:

I would be inclined to add `MemberAddress` as a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to `dbo.Member` though, something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Member
ADD MemberAddress AS 
    (LTRIM(ISNULL(Title + ' ', '') + ForeName + ' ' + Surname) + ',' + 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(AddressLine1, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE AddressLine1 + ',' END  + 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(AddressLine2, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE AddressLine2 + ',' END  + 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(AddressLine3, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE AddressLine3 + ',' END  + 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(Town, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE Town + ',' END +
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(PostCode, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE PostCode END;
```

Comment: Computed column ... nice!

Answer (score 0):

Would your stored proc be better if the code was just this?

```
DECLARE @FullAddress as varchar(250)

SELECT  FullAddress = LTRIM(ISNULL(Title + ' ', '') + ForeName + ' ' + Surname)
        + CHAR(10)
        + ISNULL(Member.AddressLine1 + CHAR(10),'')
        + ISNULL(Member.AddressLine2 + CHAR(10),'')
        + ISNULL(Member.AddressLine3 + CHAR(10),'')
        + ISNULL(Member.Town + CHAR(10),'')
        + ISNULL(Member.PostCode + CHAR(10),'')
FROM Member
WHERE MemberID = @MemberID

RETURN @FullAddress
```

Comment: Yes Cheers Guys I just Spotted htis myself also SET FullAddress = FullAddress + AddressLine + CHAR(10) was taking the values before anything was set?